# Implementing Federated Auth for Sitecore 9.2

Tags: identity-server, federated-authentication, adfs

Trying to implement Federated Authentication with ADFS for `Sitecore 9.2 CM Instance`, Following this blog post -

http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2018/03/sitecore-federated-authentication-part-2-google-and-facebook-app-and-the-custom-processor.html

But Unable to get the buttons for Facebook or Google to come up on the screen. Do I need to implement anything else as well

Or since this is Identity Server I need to implement a sub-provider within the Sitecore Identity server website for the same?

Comment: Hi @Abhay I noticed this question is related to this one, https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24782/sitecore-9-2-identity-server-with-adfs-and-openid  where I have given an answer on ADFS. Does this work for you?

Comment: thanks for your response Julius , yes implementing provider on IDs is the option I went with to implement this functionality

Comment: Follow this article https://maheshraghupathi.wordpress.com/2020/10/22/sitecore-93-adfs-integration-with-si/ , I implemented it in 9.3.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Service(typeof(IFedAuthLoginButtonService))]
public class FedAuthLoginButtonService : IFedAuthLoginButtonService
{
    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="FedAuthLoginButtonService"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pipelineManager">The base core pipeline manager.</param>
    public FedAuthLoginButtonService(BaseCorePipelineManager pipelineManager)
    {
        this.PipelineManager = pipelineManager;
        this.GetRedirectUrlService = new GetRedirectUrlService();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the pipeline manager.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The pipeline manager.
    /// </value>
    private BaseCorePipelineManager PipelineManager { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the redirect url service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The the redirect url service.
    /// </value>
    private GetRedirectUrlService GetRedirectUrlService { get; }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all login buttons for the custom identity providers.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>list of <see cref="FedAuthLoginButtonModel" />/></returns>
    public IEnumerable<FedAuthLoginButtonModel> GetAll()
    {
        var returnUrl = this.GetRedirectUrlService.GetRedirectUrl(AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated);
        var args = new GetSignInUrlInfoArgs(Context.Site.Name, returnUrl);
        GetSignInUrlInfoPipeline.Run(this.PipelineManager, args);
        if (args.Result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not retrieve federated authentication logins");
        }
        return args.Result.Select(CreateFedAuthLoginButton).ToArray();
    }

    #region Subroutines

    private static FedAuthLoginButtonModel CreateFedAuthLoginButton(SignInUrlInfo signInInfo)
    {
        var caption = signInInfo.IdentityProvider;
        string iconClass = null;
        switch (signInInfo.IdentityProvider.ToLower())
        {
            case "facebook":
                iconClass = "fab fa-facebook-square";
                break;
            case "google":
                iconClass = "fa fa-google-plus-square";
                break;
            case "linkedin":
                iconClass = "fa fa-linkedin";
                break;
            case "twitter":
                iconClass = "fa fa-twitter";
                break;
            default:
                iconClass = "fa fa-cloud";
                break;
        }

        return new FedAuthLoginButtonModel
        {
            Provider = signInInfo.IdentityProvider,
            IconClass = iconClass,
            Href = signInInfo.Href,
            Caption = caption,
        };
    }

    #endregion
}



Try to implement this and get the list of buttons wherever you want like this:


@if (Model.LoginButtons.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var loginLink in Model.LoginButtons)
                    {
                        <form action="@loginLink.Href" method="post" class="form- 
signin">
                            @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(loginLink.IconClass))
                            {
                                <button onclick=""><i class="@loginLink.IconClass" 
style="line-height: 0;"></i></button>
                            }
                        </form>
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am trying this for CM instance.

Answer (score 0):

We just need to add the , and that will automatically add the button. Reference: http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2018/02/sitecore-federated-authentication-part-1-authentication-google-facebook-identity-providers.html

```
<identityProvider id="Google" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
  <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
  <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
  <!--This text will be showed for button-->
  <caption>Log in with Google</caption>
  <icon>/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/Google.jpg</icon>
  <!--Domain name which will be added when create a user-->
  <domain>sitecore</domain>
  <triggerExternalSignOut>true</triggerExternalSignOut>
  <!--list of identity transfromations which are applied to the provider when a user signin-->
  <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
    <!--SetIdpClaim transformation-->
    <transformation name="set idp claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
  </transformations>
</identityProvider>
```

Also make sure you check the comment added in this page http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2018/03/sitecore-federated-authentication-part-2-google-and-facebook-app-and-the-custom-processor.html.

That resolved the cookie related issues we faced.