# Identity-Server with ADFS and OpenID

Tags: identity-server, openid-connect

Official Sitecore documentation is very minimalistic in many points ;-)

Has someone already implemented an `IdentityServer` provider to work with `ADFS (not Azure AD) and OpenID with Sitecore 9.2`?

I have only found https://github.com/istern/Sitecore.IdentityServer.ADFS for 9.1 - but looks like there have been a couple of changes since 9.1?

best regards,
Markus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have actually blogged about how to implement this, though I am using Sitecore 9.3 in my scenario (I believe this should work in 9.2 as well)

You need to do the following:

1. Create a Sitecore Host Plugin for ADFS using OpenID. The key to this plugin is to specify these options below. I have added a screenshot of my implementation (link to Github on my blog post below too)

   ```
       options.SignInScheme          = "idsrv.external";
       options.ResponseType          = "id_token";
       options.CallbackPath          = "/signin-adfs";
   ```

[image: Adfs-OpenId]

2. Deploy your plugin to your SI instance. Again if you haven't done this before, you will find details on my blog (or from Siteocore Docs). In brief, your plugin should be deployed in the `sitecoreruntime` sub-folder on your SI `wwwroot` folder
3. Configure your ADFS and generate `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` You will need this in your configuration for the plugin. Also remember to set the Callback URL in your ADFS to `"/signin-adfs"`

Hope this works for you. 
[I have blogged about this in details, including related post on creating Sitecore Host plugins.](https://360agileweb.wordpress.com/2020/03/02/sitecore-host-part-four/)

Comment: thanks looks really good - im am wondering which effect the options.CallbackPath = "/signin-idsrv" and signout path has - I have it set with options.CallbackPath = "/signin-idsrv"; and without client-secret and looks like this is also working... so is your adfs configuration really configured with openid - or something similar...  currently i have the problem that the cookiesize saved from sitecore gets too large - cause of too many groups adfs returns....

Comment: Great that this has worked for you. The key thing is so long as the options.CallbackPath = "/signin-idsrv" matches your ADFS portal configuration, that will be fine. Otherwise you will get an error message. I didn't come across the  cookiesize issue, I suppose you can try tweak the settings for that too.